# What is causing this basic dhash query VirusTotal API Python sample code to persistently produce 404 errors?

Tags: python, api

New to using VirusTotal API and figuring this out will open the door to much more. I was expecting a dhash value return. The code that follows is persistently resulting the in the following error even with "MY_API_KEY" updated to my key copied directly from my VirusTotal profile:

**Error retrieving dhash value: 404 - {"error":{"code":"NotFoundError","message":"Resource not found."}}**

---

```
import requests
# Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your actual VirusTotal API key
API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY"
DOMAIN = "google.com"
# Construct the URL to request the dhash value for the domain
url = f"https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/domains/{DOMAIN}/dhash"
# Set the API headers
headers = {"x-apikey": API_KEY}
# Make the API request
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Get the dhash value from the response
    dhash = response.json()["data"]["id"]
    print(f"The dhash value for {DOMAIN} is: {dhash}")
else:
    print(f"Error retrieving dhash value: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Online APIv3 includes sample code generator to retrieve a set of domain attributes as a json object that includes "dhash" value for paid user API access (not the free API key).
Link: https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/domain-info

Sample code that retrieves dash value by parsing domain object attributes:

```
import requests
# return list of values matching key in json object with recursive search
def find_key(dictionary, target_key):
# Check if the target key is in the current dictionary
    if target_key in dictionary:
        return dictionary[target_key]
    else:
        # Recursively search any nested dictionaries
        for value in dictionary.values():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                result = find_key(value, target_key)
                if result is not None:
                    return result
        # If the target key is not found, return None
         return None

base_url= "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/domains/"

# update to your VirusTotal API key 
API_KEY = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" 

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "x-apikey": API_KEY }

response = requests.get(base_url+"google.com", headers=headers)

# Parse the response text as a JSON object into a nested dictionary
data = response.json()

print(response.text)
print("dhash results #1 - direct reference:", data["data"]["attributes"]["favicon"]["dhash"])
print("dhash results #2 - recursive find_key lookup: ", 
find_key(data,"dhash"))
```

---

An excerpt of results from running the example code above follow:

```
{
"data": {
    "attributes": {
       <snip>
```

**dhash results #1 - direct reference: e89e931939338ee8**

**dhash results #2 - recursive find_key lookup:  e89e931939338ee8**